# How can I revert changes done to python packages?

Tags: python, debugging

I'm debugging an issue on a staging, and I've added a bunch of logging statements to a 3rd party package. Once I'm done with that, I'd like to get them back to their original state. In ruby, I could do a `gem pristine lib_name` and that would restore the lib to it's original source code.

It might be relevant to mention that I'm modifying code that was installed with `sudo pip install some_pkg`.

What's the usual way of reverting any changes done to a lib?

Comment: Not sure how much it helps your current situation but using virtualenvs/condaenvs would remove the need to revert

Comment: Yeah, I know ... however I'm not in charge of the deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On Linux:**

Just type the following command in a terminal (with `pip`, `pip2` or `pip3`, accordingly to the Python version you're targetting):

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall some_pkg
```

**On Windows:**

Open an admin terminal, and run the following command (ditto):

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall some_pkg
```

Comment: What about Windows?

Comment: Could this be applied to the entire `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @Rightleg, I think the same but w/o sudo

Comment: @RedEyed Well it doesn't seem to work. I'd be glad to find a solution for Windows though

Comment: @Rightleg, did you run it with admin, are there any errors?

Comment: I run it both as normal user and admin, and only got the typical "requirements already satisfied" message.

Comment: @Rightleg, try pip3

Comment: @RedEyed Nope. `pip3` is not a command, and anyway `pip --version` tells me I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: @RedEyed Yep, that was it. I'm not sure the `--no-cache-dir` flag is actually required, since I could make it run without it... but that seems to work anyway, +1.

Comment: @Rightleg, yes, I checked it and it works w/o `--no-cache-dir`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

`pip install -r requirements.txt --force --upgrade`

Comment: Won't this force new versions to be installed?

Comment: Not when you are using a requirements.txt which specifies version. So `packagename==version` should be there in your requirements.txt and this will not install the latest version, but the version you specified

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have one "requriemnt.txt" file which you want to revert back packages to:

```
#remove all currently installed packages
pip freeze > remove.txt
pip uninstall -r remove.txt
#re-insatll all packages 
pip install -r requriement.txt
```

This ensures that you also remove all unwanted packages